# Why are variable length arrays in C considered dangerous?

Tags: c, c99

The Linux Kernel recently removed all use of Variable Length Arrays, due to performance and security reasons. ([Source](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Kills-The-VLA))

What are these security reasons? What makes variable length arrays dangerous?

Comment: These can easily overflow the stack, even if used correctly otherwise.

Comment: You write: `int array[n];` — do you check that `n` is big enough (not negative, not zero) and small enough (not going to blow the remaining space on the stack)?  Do you know how much space is left on the stack?